# ASP drop downlists in Firefox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, firefox

I am currently working on a webpage that uses drop down lists to dynamically load data.

If I select an item from the drop down list and, straight after the data is loaded, I immediately try to select a different item (as if I had miss-clicked the first time around), nothing happens. It works fine if I click a second time.

It also works fine if I select an item, click anywhere else and then try to select a different item again.

This issue does not occur in Chrome or IE or versions of Firefox which predate Firefox v33

Here is my code's basic function and how it is done. Please note the first 2 times I select a menu item is works fine, only on the third time does the problem start occurring.

```
protected void ddlstMonitor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (ddlstRole.SelectedIndex >= 0 && ddlstMonitor.SelectedValue != "-None-" && ddlstRole.SelectedValue != "-None-")
{
  loadconfig(ddlstRole.SelectedValue, ddlstMonitor.SelectedValue);
}
else
{
  for (int x = 1; x <= count; x++) //hides all the controls made visible by the previous selection
  {
    ((Label)pnlConfig.FindControl("Label" + x.ToString())).Visible = false;
    ((TextBox)pnlConfig.FindControl("TextBox" + x.ToString())).Visible = false;
  }
  btnSave.Visible = true;
  conf1.Visible = true;
  val1.Visible = true;
  lblConfig.Text = "Please select a Monitor for the configuration settings to be loaded.";
}
lbl23.Text = "0";
}
```

And the loadconfig() does the following.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(dataBase))
  {
    sqlConnection.Open();
    try
    {
      SqlCommand sqlCommand;
      SqlDataReader sqlDataReader;

      //open the connection


      //setup command
      sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand();
      sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
      sqlCommand.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      sqlCommand.Parameters.Clear();
      sqlCommand.CommandText = query;

     //Parameters are added using the drop-down menu's selected items

      //execute the query
      sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
      lstType = new List<string> { };
      for (int x = 1; x <= count; x++) //all the relevant previously visible controls are made invisible
      {
        ((Label)pnlConfig.FindControl("Label" + x.ToString())).Visible = false;
        ((TextBox)pnlConfig.FindControl("TextBox" + x.ToString())).Visible = false;
      }
      if (sqlDataReader.HasRows)
      {
        int i = 1;
        count = 1;

        while (sqlDataReader.Read()) //The controls are loaded with new values.
        {
         ((TextBox)pnlConfig.FindControl("TextBox" + i.ToString())).Attributes["TextChanged"] = "TextBox1_TextChanged";

          ((TextBox)pnlConfig.FindControl("TextBox" + i.ToString())).TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
          ((Label)pnlConfig.FindControl("Label" + i.ToString())).Text = (string)sqlDataReader["CONFIGDESC"];
          ((Label)pnlConfig.FindControl("Label" + i.ToString())).Visible = true;             

          ((TextBox)pnlConfig.FindControl("TextBox" + i.ToString())).Text = (string)sqlDataReader["CUSTOMCONFIGVALUE"];
          ((TextBox)pnlConfig.FindControl("TextBox" + i.ToString())).Visible = true;



          ((Label)pnlConfig.FindControl("lbl" + i.ToString())).Text = (string)sqlDataReader["VALUEVARIABLE"];
          i++;
          count++;
        }
        lblConfig.Text = "";
        btnSave.Visible = true;            
        ((TextBox)pnlConfig.FindControl("TextBox1")).Focus();
      }
      sqlConnection.Close();
    }
catch
    {
      sqlConnection.Close();
      lblResut.Visible = true;
      lblResut.Text = "An error has occurred; unable to load configuration.";
      for (int x = 1; x <= (count + 1); x++)
      {
        ((Label)pnlConfig.FindControl("Label" + x.ToString())).Visible = false;
        ((TextBox)pnlConfig.FindControl("TextBox" + x.ToString())).Visible = false;
      }
    }
  }
```

And here is the drop down list

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstMonitor" runat="server" 
AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" 
onselectedindexchanged="ddlstMonitor_SelectedIndexChanged" TabIndex="2">
<asp:ListItem>-None-</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Please provide the code you have so far.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?? also post some code. Imagining becomes easy if you post some code related to it..!

Comment: I thought maybe due to the fact that clicking on anything else before selecting an item again seems to fix it that setting focus to various objects would work. It didn't. I then tried disabling and enabling the list once an item was selected. It didn't work either. Firefox suggested running in safe mode without addons and restarting the browser from the about:support menu. This also did nothing
I tried changing the way in which the data is loaded but that didn't change anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code, I am inclined to point toward a few items I see when this happens (form basically is unusable for a period).  Are they operating within an UpdatePanel and therefore causing themselves all to databind?   Sometimes "directing" the user where to click with visible is a solution.  Sometimes it's a matter of making sure one selectedindexchanged event is only loading one thing, and sometimes you might have to get the db admin to tune up a query and make sure you are not loading a dropdownbox with 3 seconds worth of data pull.

But start with the UpdatePanel.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it is being used.Also would this not affect it in IE as well?